# Replace a date in a text file with today's date using powershell

Tags: powershell

I would like to achieve a very similar outcome as discussed in this thread:
https://serverfault.com/questions/475325/replacing-a-line-or-date-in-a-text-file-using-powershell

I encountered two problems:
1) The date in my file is slightly different so the script does not pick it up and my required output format of the date is also different. I need the date in CCYY-MM-DD format (Same as input)

Here are a few lines of my text file starting line 40, so date is in line 44:

```
</script>
 <div id="divMain" style="background:transparent;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;position:relative;width:960px;height:640px;">

  <div style="position:absolute;left:15px;top:79px;width:650px;height:508px;">
    <iframe src="http://free.timeanddate.com/countdown/i5bwxdc1/n269/cf12/cm0/cu4/ct4/cs1/ca0/cr0/ss0/cac000/cpc000/pcf9f/tcfff/fs225/szw576/szh243/tatAantal%20minute%20en%20sekondes/tac00f/tptTe%20laat/tpcf00/matvoor%20ons%20in%20die%20kar%20moet%20klim/mac00f/mptmet/mpc000/iso2016-08-18T07:10:00/bas4/pd2" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" width="1065" height="280"></iframe>
  </div>
  <img src="wpimages/wpa1e7d92d_06.png" alt="" width="39" height="36" style="position:absolute;left:333px;top:43px;width:39px;height:36px;">
</div>
```

The powershell script below does not pick up the date string in my file and does not convert/replace the date , but writes out the file exactly like the input file

Powershell Script I tried:

```
$infile = "C:\temp\input.html"
$outfile = "C:\temp\output.html"
$content = Get-Content -Path $infile
$content[71] = $content[71] -replace "([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.]([1-9]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d", [datetime]::Today.ToShortDateString()
$content | Set-Content $outfile
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards

Frits

Comment: If the content you need to change is on line 44, why are you altering the 72nd element of `$content`? `Get-Content` (unless you use `-Raw`) returns one array element per line of content.

Comment: Just a typo: I stripped some lines out just to make it easier. 71 Should be 43. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Change the right-hand side operands of the `-replace` operator to suit your needs:

```
$string -replace '(19|20)\d\d[- /.]([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.]([1-9]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])', [datetime]::Today.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
```

---

If you need to change line 44 specifically, target index `43`:

```
$content[43] = $content[43] -replace '(19|20)\d\d[- /.]([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.]([1-9]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])', [datetime]::Today.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply: I will try and provide feedback

Comment: I managed to get it to work in my temp directory structure and moved the files to area where I will be using it, but now it refuses to update the file.
Feel like an idiot!

I will copy the related text now

Comment: @FritsErasmus You're going to have to provide a little more detail than "it refuses to update the file" if you want any qualified help :)

Comment: Mathias, sorry struggled to get text into website

Comment: @FritsErasmus Click the [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38994913/edit) under your question and add the additional information :)